# How to rotate a region in Eyeshot so that its plane normal is equal to a vector?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I need to draw a prism between 2 point. So I have defined a `Region` like this:

```
Region r1 = Region.CreateRectangle(Model.Width, Model.Height);
r1.Translate(point1);
```

Now I need to rotate `r1` to face `point2` and then do:

```
r1.ExtrudeAsMesh(distanceBetweenPoints, 0, Mesh.natureType.Plain);
```

But Eyeshot doesn't let me change the plane normal of `r1` directly. Is there any way to achieve this (other than doing the math by hand)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, But I solved it like this:

```
Vector3D theVector = new Vector3D(point1, point2);
Plane thePlane = new Plane(point1, theVector);
Region r1 = Region.CreateRectangle(thePlane, Model.Width, Model.Height, true);
Mesh m1 = r1.ExtrudeAsMesh(theVector, 0, Mesh.natureType.Plain);
```

Comment: That answer has nothing to do with the question. question is about rotate. Example shows a translate and answer is about extruding at fix point.